# Send Apple Push Notification via AWS Lambda/Python as JSON with custom variable Message

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, boto3

Hello i'm trying to send push notifications like this

```
message3 = {"APNS_SANDBOX":"{\"aps\": {\"alert\": \"some alert\",\"sound\": \"default\",\"badge\": 1},\"message\": \"additional information\",\"id\": 1234}"}

response = client.publish(
    #TopicArn='string',
    TargetArn = someEndpoint,
    Message = json.dumps(message3),
    MessageStructure= 'json'
    #Subject='string',
)
```

Everything works fine. But i need the alert to be variable. If i try to put a custom text variable in the message3 json object, i keep getting this error:

```
"errorType": "ClientError",
"errorMessage": "An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the Publish operation: Invalid parameter: Message Reason: Invalid notification for protocol APNS_SANDBOX: Notification is malformed"
```

Can anybody help? Thank you!!

Comment: How did you try to customize `message3`? Is there an example you can share?

Comment: hi, thank you for the quick response! The function is triggert by a dynamodb insert event and i am building a string variable from the inserted record. but even if just use a simple variable like sampleText = "test" and try to exchange \"some alert\" with sampleText in message 3 i will get the error.

Comment: How do you exchange the text? It sounds like you're using `.replace()` or a regular expression. You should edit the message as a normal Python dictionary and then dump it back as JSON and put it in `APNS_SANDBOX`.

Comment: That sounds good! I think i'm doing it wrong! what i was doing was: message3 = {"APNS_SANDBOX":"{\"aps\": {\"alert\": sampleText,\"sound\": \"default\",\"badge\": 1},\"message\": \"additional information\",\"id\": 1234}"}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to work like this.

```
test = "test"
message = {'aps': {'alert': test, 'sound': 'default','badge': 1},'message': 'additional information','id': 1234}
dumped = json.dumps(message)

message3 = {"APNS_SANDBOX":dumped}

response = client.publish(
    #TopicArn='string',
    TargetArn = someEndpoint,
    Message = json.dumps(message3),
    MessageStructure= 'json'
    #Subject='string',
)
```

Is that what you meant, @kichik? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.